# Is it possible to create an instance of a generic type in vala

Tags: generics, vala

I need to create an instance of a generic type in vala, but apparently this isn't supported. Is there an alternative to achieve similar behavior?

```
class MorningGreater {
        public string greeting;
        public string name;
        public MorningGreater(string _greeting, string _name) {
                greeting = _greeting;
                name = _name;
        }
        public void raining() {
                print(greeting + name + " raining morning");    
        }
}
class NameGreater<T> {
        public NameGreater(string name) {
                ///// This is the problem:
                ///// i can't create an instance of T
                var a = new T("good", name);
                a.raining();
        }
}
int main() {
        new NameGreater<MorningGreater>("Bob");
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `valac main.vala` It gives this error

```
main.vala:16.11-16.29: error: `NameGreater.T' is not a class, struct, or error code
        var a = new T("good", name);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't even guarantee that you're going to create an object. What if you did `new NameGreater<int>`. This will also be a problem when you do `a.raining()`.

It would be possible to create a delegate that instantiates your class and pass the delegate:

```
delegate T Create<T>(String greeting, String name);
class NameGreater<T> {
        public NameGreater(Create<T> creator, string name) {
                ///// This is the problem:
                ///// i can't create an instance of T
                var a = creator("good", name);
                a.raining();
        }
}
int main() {
        new NameGreater<MorningGreater>((g, n) => new MonrningGreater(g, n), "Bob");
        return 0;
}
```

The `a.raining()` problem needs [generic type bound](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/issues/271), which are not supported in Vala.

Comment: Or better still use an interface so the right properties and methods are available. Even if the generic type passed was instantiable there is no assurance that it has a `raining()` method.